# Prisma-like voice transformation in recorded speech

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

Recently a photo-transformation application [Prisma](http://prisma-ai.com) has gained a lot of attention thanks to its ability to recreate a picture with a non-trivial style with the help of machine learning algorithms. Are there methods that can achieve a similar effect with a sound of recorded speech, by changing the voice according to a certain model.

As far as I understand, Prisma works in 2 steps:

1. extracts distinct features of an image a regions of the input picture;
2. redraws each feature with a style parameterised by the neural network which knows how each feature should be trasnformed;

Is there an equivalent voice-invariant features of a recorded speech, which then can be transformed according to some model?